# Exception in plugin Android Studio java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsComboBoxUI

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm trying to open the tab attributes in IntelliJ IDE.
It's an error when I click on View Fewer attributes.
This is the error log. Can anybody help me fix this? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

**Stack Trace**

```
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.property.editors.EnumEditor$CustomComboBox.setUI(EnumEditor.java:470)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComboBox.updateUI(JComboBox.java:277)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComboBox.init(JComboBox.java:236)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComboBox.<init>(JComboBox.java:230)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.ComboBoxWithWidePopup.<init>(ComboBoxWithWidePopup.java:15)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.ComboBox.<init>(ComboBox.java:44)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.property.editors.EnumEditor$CustomComboBox.<init>(EnumEditor.java:440)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.editors.NlEnumEditor.createForInspectorWithBrowseButton(NlEnumEditor.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.inspector.IdInspectorProvider$IdInspectorComponent.<init>(IdInspectorProvider.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.inspector.IdInspectorProvider.createCustomInspector(IdInspectorProvider.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.inspector.IdInspectorProvider.createCustomInspector(IdInspectorProvider.java:39)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.property.inspector.InspectorProviders.createInspectorComponents(InspectorProviders.java:54)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.property.inspector.InspectorPanel.setComponent(InspectorPanel.java:260)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertiesPanel.setItems(NlPropertiesPanel.java:281)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.property.PropertiesManager.lambda$null$0(PropertiesManager.java:247)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:878)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:466)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:704)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:465)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.3.4] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@6c933fd8
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:75)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: I'm getting this when attempting to use the Design view on a layout xml file in an Android project open in IDEA.

Answer (score 3):

This pull request will fix the issue:
https://github.com/JetBrains/android/pull/17

Comment: It's always good to include content along with links. Otherwise, the OP will have no idea where they are clicking into or the link may no longer valid. For more information see [how to write good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)